# iTextSharp Extract text from Identity-H encoding using c#

Tags: encoding, itext, extract

I use iTextSharp Library.
And I want parse Text from Pdf Document.

use 'GetTextFromPage()' method is very good.

but it's doesn't know text position.

I want get text and image in order.

so i want know that object's position.

so i doesn't use GetTextFromPage() method.

Now I get the text info(for token??). but that text encoding is 'Identity-H'

So, I don't know that text.

how I convert??

Comment: You had better try the other way around, extend a `TextExtractionStrategy` to also return coordinates.

Comment: Hi @mkl I've examined the problem and I think there is indeed a problem with `Identity` CMaps. I have posted some code to the SVN repository. I think this fixes the problem, but it is hard to test without sufficient sample PDFs. Maybe the OP can post a PDF we can use.

Comment: @이대연 Can you share a PDF that reproduces the problem? I may have fixed it, but I need documents to test my solution.